# Android location update using fused returns null. How to ensure I get it from foreground activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I need the location once in my foreground activity. But I get a null response.

Weirdly once I open google maps the location callback returns a valid object. What is google maps doing that I'm not? How do I ensure the value is not null in my foreground activity?

code:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun getLastLocation(): LiveData<Location> {
    registerLocationUpdates()
    try {
        this.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context).lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { loc: Location? ->
            if (loc != null) {
                util.toast(util.getStringRes(R.string.fetching_location, "${loc.latitude}, ${loc.longitude}"))
                postValue(loc)
            } else util.toast(util.getStringRes(R.string.null_location))
        }.addOnFailureListener { e: Exception ->
            Log.e(LocationModule::class.java.canonicalName, e.toString())
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Log.e(LocationModule::class.java.canonicalName, ex.toString())
    }
    return this
}

private fun getFusedLocationProviderClient(context: Context): FusedLocationProviderClient {
    if (fusedLocationProviderClient == null) fusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    return fusedLocationProviderClient!!
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I have read some solutions but for now I have not been able to solve the problem